# Django: command management call from model, from view or from where?

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I am new on Python3 and DJango.

I am writing an app where the user can register a Company using Company Name and AWS Access Key and Secret Key. 
I will use the Access and Secret key to make a inventory "Discovery" of the AWS Account.

Well, I want what every time an user register a company (click to create) django executes a management command called infra_discovery.py inside my app_folder/management/commands (that is working fine when I call via python manage.py infra_discovery).

I have the following model:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from empresa.models import Empresa

class InfraDiscovery(models.Model):
    # user will fill this three fiels: 
    infra_empresa = models.ForeignKey('empresa.Empresa', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True )    
    infra_aws_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    infra_aws_secret = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    # my script called infra_discovery have to fill this fields:
    infra_vpc     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )
    infra_ec2     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )
    infra_ebs     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )
    infra_rds     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )
    infra_vpn     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )
    infra_bill    = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('infrastructure_discovery_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I really don't know how to make django fulfill this fields using my script at every time user clicks in "create" button;

What are your suggestion to me?

Comment: A management command is supposed to be called manually. Why don't you call your python code just in the save methode of the model (override the save method).

Comment: @ger.s.brett Sorry about my poor knowledge in Django in Python; I look about this in django documentation i now i have implemented in the model, as you said.